# mySQL transfer 8000+ rows from one table to another PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am working on a script in which I want to transfer 8000+ rows from one table to another table in another database with selected columns. By far I have thought to fetch the selected columns of the entire source table using `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` as a `$result` array and then prepare a mySQL insert statement using `PDO::prepare()` method as

```
INSERT INTO targetTable (targetColumn1,targetColumn2...) VALUES 
(sourceRow1ForColumn1,sourceRow1ForColumn2,..),
(sourceRow2ForColumn1,sourceRow2ForColumn2,..),
(sourceRow3ForColumn1,sourceRow3ForColumn2,...),...
```

But I think that this is not an efficient way and there should be an optimal way to do what I want to do. Is there any better way I can do what I want to do?

Comment: use cli to export to .sql file, replace table and column names, import sql?

Comment: I really don't want the process to be manual as non-technical people are going to use what I am doing.

Comment: `insert into targetTable select * from sourceTable` ?

Comment: 8000 records is trivial. `fetchAll()` from the source table, loop the data, and insert one at a time into the destination table. It should take no more than 30 seconds. If you are trying to us the multi-insert query like you have shown then it is prone to error and exceeding the length restriction.

Comment: That is an even bad idea I think. @MonkeyZeus

Comment: Same server @RyanVincent

Comment: Is this a one-time thing? I think you should benchmark how long it takes with each approach. If it finishes in an acceptable amount of time then I would think that it's sufficient.

Comment: It is going to be run on daily bases. moreover right now there are 8000 rows, what if rows exceed to 80000 or even 800000 we never know. @MonkeyZeus

Comment: Well then `insert into destination_table (col1, col2) select col1, col2 from source_table` **is** the absolute fastest query that you can hope for. If you honestly expect this to grow to 800,000 and you are truly worried about the future then you need to re-evaluate why you are doing this in the first place. It sounds like a very bad or legacy database design. Look into data-warehousing and hosting master-slave DBs if you want to remain at peak efficiency. Even `insert into..select...` will have trouble when you reach 8,000,000 rows.

Comment: Thank you @MonkeyZeus for suggestion and of course it is not a good design but that is nothing to do with me. I will definitely suggest this to my client as I was already thinking of this.

Comment: I see. Well then the answer provided by [spencer7593](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36924330/2191572) is honestly the right choice for now. If you can convince your client into implementing some sort of data-warehousing then that will be the absolute best choice.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm writing the script now as spencer7593 suggested. Once I test run it, I will be accepting that answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way to do this would be to use an INSERT ... SELECT statement.

```
INSERT INTO targetTable (targetColumn1,targetColumn2)
SELECT expr1, expr2 FROM one_table
```

`expr1` and `expr2` represent expressions that return the values that you want to insert into `targetColumn1` and `targetColumn2` columns, respectively.

The expressions could be as simple reference to a colum name in the source table.

---

If the tables are in different databases (schemas) on the same MySQL instance, you can qualify the table name with the name of the database. (An unqualified table name refers to a table in the current database (i.e. USE mydatabase.)

If your current database is the target database, qualify the name table in the FROM clause

```
INSERT INTO targetTable (targetColumn1,targetColumn2)
SELECT expr1, expr2 FROM anotherdb.one_table
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

If the current database contains the source table, qualify the name of the targetTable.

Or just qualify both table names, and it doesn't matter what database is current.

---

Just connect to MySQL as a user that has sufficient privileges on each table.

```
GRANT SELECT ON anotherdb.one_table TO myuser@'%';
GRANT INSERT ON targetdb.targetTable TO myuser@'%';
```

---

If the insert attempts to insert a row that violates a unique constraint in the targetTable, the same thing would happen with an INSERT ... SELECT as would with the INSERT ... VALUES statement... the statement will fail.

If you want to disregard errors about duplicates, and just skip over those rows, then use  an INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT atatement.  (The IGNORE keywords causes MySQL not to skip over the row, rather than throwing an error when a unique key constraint is violated.

Or, you could write the SELECT statement to exclude rows that already exist in the target table.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that target table is in a different database. Let me edit my question

Comment: A different database on the same MySQL instance, or on a different MySQL instance?

Comment: both databases are on same server. Source is in database1.source and target is database2.target

Comment: @ZohaibAslam if the other db schema is on the same machine (same mysql instance), just state the db names as well. `insert into db1.tableA (col1,col2) select col3, col4 from db2.tableB`

Comment: I don't know if user permissions do play their role doing what you suggested. I mean for db1 I have to put user1 in connection string and its credentials but for db2 there's a user2

Comment: Also I just thought what will happen if there a duplicate value comes from source table.

Comment: This answer is making quite a sense, thank you. Can you please tell if there's a way to update rest of the fields if duplicate key value comes using this approach?

Comment: An `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` statement can be used to "catch" duplicate key errors, and update the existing row.

Answer (score 1):

If it's going to be done one time, you do not need to care of the performance.

put set_time_limit(0); at the beginning of your PHP file.

Then, connect to your first DB. read the data from the source table and store in an array.

Now, disconnect and connect to the new DB and insert the array data to the target table

And for caring the duplicate keys, you can use INSERT OR UPDATE ON DUPLICATE in your query.

If your records are going to be huge, you might have problem with the memory. So, it's better to get the count before storing into the array. Then, do the process in a loop and at the end of each loop, free up the array by unset(). So, you split the records and keep your memory usage in a proper way.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that target table is in a different database. Let me edit my question.

Comment: @ZohaibAslam, So, I changed the answer

Comment: Thanks, insert frequency is almost 5/day. Also I wonder how I can cater duplicate key values from source table.

Comment: Do you do it manually each time? or there is a scheduled running script?

Comment: It's going to be a crone job.

Comment: @ZohaibAslam, If it's in cron job, you are not worried about the time. Also, I updated my answer for your duplicate key concern.

Comment: Almost solved my problem but I still want this to be a little bit optimal than your suggestions as right now there are 8000 rows but in future there might be 800000 and this approach will fire-back for sure.